# Android contact query

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

I have a problem in querying phonebook contacts. What I need to do is get a list of contacts that have both phone and email entered or are of a specific type.

Basically like this:

```
public static final String SELECTION =
    "("+ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER +"='1') OR " + RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "='" + Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "'";
```

Now, the problem is, that `RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE` does not exist in the `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`, which I use with my query. I'm guessing I'd need to join another table, but have no idea how to do so.

Can anyone help me here, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to read a raw contact along with all the data associated with it is by using the `ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity` directory. If the raw contact has data rows, the Entity cursor will contain a row for each data row. If the raw contact has no data rows, the cursor will still contain one row with the raw contact-level information.

```
Uri rawContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId);
 Uri entityUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(rawContactUri, Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
 Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(entityUri,
          new String[]{RawContacts.SOURCE_ID, Entity.DATA_ID, Entity.MIMETYPE, Entity.DATA1},
          null, null, null);
 try {
     while (c.moveToNext()) {
         String sourceId = c.getString(0);
         if (!c.isNull(1)) {
             String mimeType = c.getString(2);
             String data = c.getString(3);
             //decide here based on mimeType, see comment later
         }
     }
 } finally {
     c.close();
 }
```

You will have to filter the result based on the mimeType

For example, if the mimeType is `Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`, then the column `DATA1` stores the phone number, but if the data kind is `Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`, then `DATA1` stores the email address.

This way you won't have to use `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` as you will directly iterate trough the items.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use `Email.CONTENT_URI` as it contains all data records of the `"vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2"` MIME type, combined with the **associated raw contact** and **aggregate contact data**.